# How do i run ```npx @727-ventures/typechain-compiler --config typechain.config.json``` for a nightly version

Tags: ink, compilation

So i am running this command  `npx @727-ventures/typechain-compiler --config typechain.config.json` to get to compile so i can write my test file for my contracts and use the typechain gotten. This is the error
`` error[E0554]: `#![feature]` may not be used on the stable release channel --> /Users/ayomide/Desktop/Work Space/Me Protocol/rusty-protocol-v0.1/contracts/global.rs:2:1 | 2 | #![feature(min_specialization)] | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ``

I understand that this is because i added  `#![feature(min_specialization)]`, but i am using the rust nightly channel , so if i cargo cotract build, it build and complies well. But when i run this  `npx @727-ventures/typechain-compiler --config typechain.config.json`
I get the problem. Even though i am still using nightly channel.

Any help please